# CryptoJS AES encrypt not using own IV

Tags: javascript, typescript, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I am trying to encrypt some data as shown below:

```
let cipherText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(phrase, this.encryptionKey, {iv: initializationV});
```

But when I check the IV after encryption by using cipherText.iv, it does not match the IV that I used.

I am generating the IV as given below:

```
let initializationV = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
```

What is the issue over here?

Comment: Please show the code which you use to compare the IV values.

Comment: console.log(cipherText.iv.toString() === initializationV.toString());

Comment: Hu, `===` is rather dangerous in case the type is just ever so slightly different types. Could you log the IV's themselves as a string and see what you get then?

Comment: Yeah. I did that and they turn out to be different.

Comment: *How* are they different? Could you show the values? Remember, we cannot see your screen! Most mistakes on crypto are encoding mistakes.

Comment: I just resolved it. Its just that when you are trying to encrypt/decrypt and you want to use your own IV, the key has to be a WordArray. It cannot be in plaintext. I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472396/how-does-cryptojs-get-an-iv-when-none-is-specified

Comment: You're welcome. I see that the answer from ArtjomB there doesn't **directly** say that the IV needs to be a word array, so feel free to answer your own question. It might be useful for future visitors.